# Why is my bash script trying to run comments as code?

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a bash script to run several python programs in a particular order and it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
python prog1.py #make database
python prog2.py #plots
python prog3.py #more plots
```

This runs fine, but when I comment out the first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
#python prog1.py #make database
python prog2.py #plots
python prog3.py #more plots
```

It crashes with:

```
./python_progs.sh: line 3: plots: command not found
```

It is as if it is ignoring the '#' in front of 'plots' and is trying to run it as code.  Another strange thing is this does not happen all the time, sometimes the second code runs with no problems, sometimes it crashes.  Am I missing something basic about how commenting works in bash scripts?

For the people commenting below here is the exact code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
python footprint_hex.py >> ./paper/qso_num.txt #this makes the footpring figures
python sed_db_read.py #makes the inital databases
python sed_db_read2.py #makes the new databases for lum and civ and modles
python sed_db_plots_paper.py #plots
python sed_db_plots_paper_png.py #plots
```

When no lines are commented it works fine but when commenting out lines 3 and 4 it crashes with:

```
./compile_dbs.sh: line 5: and: command not found
```

and when commenting out lines 3, 4, and 5 it crashes with :

```
./compile_dbs.sh: line 6: plots: command not found
```

My exact steps for running the script are:

```
./compile_dbs.sh
```

Comment: Is this the complete code exactly as in the file?

Comment: If that is the exact contents of the file, please confirm with `xxd` to hex-dump it. Make sure there aren't any invisible characters in there. Also, you can get *very* weird errors like that if you edit a shell script while its running—don't do that.

Comment: You gotta be trolling us... :S If not please update with the exact steps you are taking and check if your bash file doesn't have any strange control character. check the script using `set -x` too

Comment: I'm guessing your actual script has a single quote somewhere. That would cause bash to read past the end of the line, and past a comment delimiter

Comment: Now that I think about it I may have been editing the script while it was running.... I am so used to python were it does not matter....

Comment: What distro and/or bash version are you using? What happens if you change your bash shebang `#!/usr/bin/env sh` ?

Comment: can you try running with `#!/bin/bash -xv` whcih will give an idea what is going on ?

Comment: @derobert Concur strongly with this.  These errors are very much indicative of windows/unix newline issue (\n vs \r\n)

Comment: vim -b file_name should show newlines from windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem! I was editing the bash script while it was running, this is what caused the crashes.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on, but my guess is that it is interpreting `#plots` as an argument to script `prog2.py`

To be safe you might just want to put the comment on a separate line

Comment: Shell doesn't require comments to be on a separate line.

Comment: It looks to me that the 'command not found' error message comes from bash. So this will probably have nothing todo with prog2.py's contents.